# Dealing with reCAPTCHA in Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe, recaptcha, webdriverwait

I need to automate a web page using python selenium, but it encounters a reCaptcha, which is in another frame. I want to solve the captcha, and continue the script by clicking the login button, when the reCaptcha has been solved; However, this gets tricky, since a frame is involved, and the frame needs to switch back to the default content. Can anyone help me in this regard?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.delete_all_cookies()    
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("https://developer.syntecx.org/ptcl_ebills/signin.php")
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']/div[1]").click()
time.sleep(20)
browser.switch_to_default_content()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login']/button").click()
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you fill in the *Email* and *Password* field to click on the [recaptcha](/questions/tagged/recaptcha) you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://developer.syntecx.org/ptcl_ebills/signin.php")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#email"))).send_keys("Asad_Ullah@stackoverflow.com")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#password").send_keys("Asad_Ullah")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.recaptcha-checkbox.goog-inline-block.recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked.rc-anchor-checkbox"))).click()
  driver.switch_to_default_content()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-primary.block.full-width.m-b"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: reCAPTCHA]

Comment: Thanks for the help. How do I switch back to the main frame, and continue the script, after I've solved the reCaptcha? That's where I'm getting in trouble.

Comment: @AsadUllah Updated the answer with the step to switch back to the main frame and click on the **Login** button. Check out the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Does it wait for me to solve the captcha, and then automatically continue the script? Because I ran this in my python compiler, and it just clicks the login button after clicking the captcha.

Comment: switch_to_default_content() is deprecatede

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply wait for the checkbox to show the done icon and then the wait will be over**

Like in the code below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit() here
```

Answer (score 1):

Try do it:

Create a variable that get the main window:

```
mainWin = driver.current_window_handle
```

When u need to switch to main window:

```
driver.switch_to.window(mainWin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't switch to the iframe.

Everything you need is in `#g-recaptcha-response` and `[data-sitekey]` which are both in main context.

Comment: How do I use those to click the recaptcha and continue the script?

Comment: set the `#g-recaptcha-response` innerText, and click the button. Refer to 2captcha's docs for more info.

Comment: Would it wait for me to complete the captcha, and then continue the script as well?

Comment: You need to solve the captcha, then enter it, then submit.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a way for it to continue working when I've manually finished completing the captcha.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a solution when you encounter a reCaptcha in a login page.
Simple approach that works very good for me. Check out for login button in a login page. If it lost it's existance, than you can proceed to the next stage. So, my solution does not require any timeout. Happy automating your stuff :)

```
    def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
        return True

    login_btn_xpath = 'your login button xpath'
    while True:
        print('You can solve recaptcha during this period and hit the login button.')
        if check_exists_by_xpath(login_btn_xpath) is False:
            break
    # TODO: you can go along from here!
```